# I cannot run MNIST MWE (hello world for DL)

Tags: python, mnist, anaconda, cuda, version-control

I have installed Anaconda and want tor run MWE for MNIST **but** I'me getting this error:

> ```
> D:\STAZENE_last\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py:107:
> ```
>
> UserWarning: CUDA initialization: The NVIDIA driver on your system is
> too old (found version 9010). Please update your GPU driver by
> downloading and installing a new version from the URL:
> http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx Alternatively, go to:
> https://pytorch.org to install a PyTorch version that has been
> compiled with your version of the CUDA driver. (Triggered internally
> at ..\c10\cuda\CUDAFunctions.cpp:109.)
> return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch requires CUDA to run on Nvidia GPUs, and different versions of CUDA require different device drivers. The error message is telling you to update your device driver, or install a different version of pytorch. You can alternatively install a CPU version of Pytorch using the configuration GUI here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
by selecting Compute Platform CPU on the last line then running the command generated.